# Get latest iOS apps from iTunes Search Api

Tags: itunes-store

Is there a way to get the latest apps (or sort by release date) feature to get iOS applications from iTunes Search Api?

Thanks!

Comment: iTunes Search Api documentation doesn't query anything related to release date. I've already tried that. If I didn't why would I ask through here?

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://itunes.apple.com/search?term=cat%20physics&country=us&entity=software&limit=10&sort=recent

Comment: Sort parameter is only available in lookup requests, not in search @HenslerSoftware